# rails: render a collection of models using an specific html view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following simple problem with rails.

Let say I have a model User.
In a view, if I do:

```
<%= render User.all %>
```

The file view in views/user/_user.html.erb will be called and printed for each of the users.

How can I change this to use an specific view?
I need something like:

```
<%= render :data=>User.all :template=>"user/_user_2ndview.html"%>
```

Any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really have an instance variable named `@User` or is that a typo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `collection` option:

```
<%= render :collection => User.all, :partial => "users/user2ndview", 
           :as => :user %>
```

The view must be placed in views/users/_user2ndview

See the [Rails guides on rendering collections](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) for more details.

Comment: I get the error: undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#<Class:0xb5eebc1c>:0xb5da7608>
Cause in _user_2ndview.html I use <%= user.name %>
How can I tell render to set the users to a var called user?

Comment: <%= render :collection => User.all, :template => "user/_user_2ndview.html" as: "user" %>

Comment: @RakuN: Thank you, I almost forgot about that option :)

Comment: Still get same undefined local variable or method error.
For what you say I see, the following are equivalent?
<%= render User.all%>
And
<%= render :collection => User.all, :template => "users/_user.html", :as => :user %>
Cause the first one works and the second gives me an error.

Comment: Got it!
<%= render :collection => User.all, :partial => "user/user", :as => :user %>
So in my case: <%= render :collection => User.all, :partial => "user/user_2ndview", :as => :user %> The file new view must be in user/_user_2ndview.html.erb.

Comment: this will work: <%= render partial: user/user_2ndview, collection: User.all, as: "user" %>